# React error that says identifier 'Navbar' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make a imaginary/test website, but I get the following error:

```
Line 4:4:  Parsing error: Identifier 'Navbar' has already been declared. (4:4)
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navigationbar from './Components/Navigationbar';


let App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <Navigationbar/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Navigationbar.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar, Container, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';

let Navigationbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <Navbar bg="dark" expand="sm" variant="dark">
          <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Personal Portfolio</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#overmij">About me</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navigationbar;
```

I tried to change the names of the function to Navigationbar because I thought that was the problem but can't really solve it.

Comment: Try to save the changes and then try.

Comment: I already done that, but it does not work